# Validar código con JS en cliente

Tags: javascript, formularios

Tengo un pequeño formulario con un sólo campo para introducir un código. El cliente debería introducir el código y si este esta bien escrito, redirige a google.com, de caso contrario sólo mostrará un alerta.

Algo no funciona aquí:

```
 <form  action="" name="go">
  <input type="text" id="codigo" name="codigo" required>
  <input type="button" value="Send" onClick="comprobarCodigo()">
 </form>

 <script>
  function comprobarCodigo(){
  codigo = document.go.codigo.value

  if (codigo == P4ssW0rd)
   window.location.href='www.google.com';
 else
   alert("Wrong password, try again")
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: `P4ssW0rd` debe ir entre comillas.

Comment: @Lobos eso era, gracias. podrías publicar tu respuesta para darte el crédito a tí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se debe a que `P4ssW0rd` debe ir entre comillas porque es una cadena de texto. Si no se le colocan las comillas entonces se trataría como si fuera una variable y produce el error que la variable `P4ssW0rd` no existe.

Un consejo al trabajar con javascript: siempre tener la consola del navegador abierta y asegurarse que no se generen errores mientras el código se ejecuta.